# Возвратный суффикс "ся"

Tags: грамматика, морфология

Ну понятно, что одеваешь кого-то, а одеваешься — одеваешь себя. А как будет с глаголом "драться"? Вроде ж не себя дерёшь? И то же самое — со словом "кусаться".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Глаголы с возвратной частицей -ся делятся на несколько групп.

- **Собственно возвратные глаголы**: действие направлено на действующее лицо (т.е. возвращается к нему). Значение посфикса -ся здесь равно значению 'себя': *умываться, одеваться, бриться, защищаться, прятаться* и пр.
- **взаимно-возвратные глаголы**: одно и тоже действие совершается двумя (или несколькими) лицами. При этом каждое лицо совершает действие и принимает на себя действие: *встречаться, обниматься, здороваться, знакомиться, мириться, бороться, целоваться, переписываться* и пр.
- **Общевозвратные глаголы**, в которых постфикс -ся, делая глагол непереходным, не меняет его основного значения. Эти глаголы обозначают: 1) различные изменения в движении, положении, состоянии (*двигаться, опускаться, приземляться, возвращаться, нагибаться, останавливаться, уменьшаться* и пр.); 2) начало, продолжение и конец какого-либо явления или действия (*начинаться, продолжаться, кончиться*); 3) постоянное свойство предмета (например: *кактус колется, дерево гнется, собака кусается*).
- **Глаголы, которые без -ся не употребляются**: *смеяться, становиться, бояться, появляться, стремиться, нуждаться* и пр.
- **Безличные глаголы, обозначающие состояние, не зависящее от лица**: случается, смеркается, думается, хочется, нездоровится, не работается, не спится, не сидится и пр.)
- **Глаголы несовершенного вида со страдательным значением** (ср.: *Эксперимент проводится учеными; Памятник охраняется государством*).

Глаголы, о которых вы спрашиваете, таким образом, можно отнести к одной из названных групп: **драться** - взаимно-возвратный глагол, **кусаться** - общевозвратный глагол, обозначающие постоянное свойство предмета.

Comment: А у вас даже точнее классификация. Это "Академическая грамматика", нет? Некогда искать.

Comment: Это Грамматика русского языка в иллюстрациях К.И.Пехливанова и М.Н.Лебедева. Ее рекомендуют иностранным студентам: все очень наглядно и понятно (с картинками же!).

Comment: ОК, спасиб. Всегда подозревал, что все нетривиальное в родном языке надо объяснять примерно как иностранцам.

Answer (score 3):

И много ещё всяких... 
У возвратной частицы (или суффикса, как вы её назвали) в русском насчитывается по разным оценкам от четырёх до семи (а может и больше) семантических функций. Собтвенно-возвратная не только не единственная, но, боюсь, даже не главная.

Сравните: обижаться(на других), целоваться (друг-друга), кусаться(свойство "быть кусачей"), ругаться (с кем-то) и проч. Нигде нет прямого соответвия "обижать себя", "целовать себя", "кусать себя", "ругать себя" и т.д.

Сейчас попробую найти ссылку, недавно выдел хороший материал на эту тему.
Нет, не нашел пока, но вот есть некие соображения безымянных авторов.

§ 99. Значение возвратных глаголов.
    Возвратные глаголы, образованные от любого переходного глагола, являются непереходными: поднимать (переходный) – подниматься (непереходный), мыть (переходный) – мыться (непереходный), встретить (переходный) – встретиться (непереходный).
     П р и м е ч а н и е.  Есть такие глаголы, которые не бывают возвратными: хожу, сплю, пою. Есть, наоборот, глаголы, которые употребляются только как возвратные: боюсь, смеюсь, любуюсь, тружусь.
    Частица -ся в возвратных глаголах имеет несколько значений. Важнейшие из них следующие.
    а) Частица -ся обозначает только непереходность действия, т. е. такое действие, которое не обращено ни на какой предмет: собака кусается, лошадь мчится, море волнуется, туман поднимается.
    б) Частица -ся придаёт глаголу собственно возвратное значение: она указывает, что действие возвращается на само действующее лицо. Сравните: купать (кого?) ребёнка и купаться (т. е. купать самого себя).
    в) Частица -ся придаёт глаголу взаимное значение: она указывает, что действие происходит между двумя или несколькими действующими лицами или предметами. При этих глаголах можно поставить вопрос с кем? с чем? Например: встречаться (с кем? – с товарищем), бороться, сражаться.
    г) Частица -ся придаёт глаголу страдательное значение. При этих глаголах можно ставить вопросы кем? чем? Например: Горные породы (подлеж.) размываются (чем?) водой. Сравните: Вода размывает горные породы.
    д) Частица -ся придаёт глаголу безличное значение. При этом она указывает, что действие совершается как бы само собой, помимо чьей-либо воли. При этих глаголах можно поставить вопросы: кому? чему? Например: не спится (кому?) мне (сравните: он не спит), ему не хочется, мне думается. 
http://stcreserv.narod.ru/Tutorial/glagol-2.html

Тоже пять значений насчитывают.