# Правильно ли будет написать "продаётся квартира"

Tags: стилистика

Как правильно следует писать: "продам (-ю) квартиру" или можно "продаётся квартира".
Может ли неодушевлённый предмет сам с собой производить действие?

Comment: Ваш ответ не вносит никакой ясности. Ваш ответ совершенно не показывает функцию постфикса *"-ся"*, он только добавляет лишний член предложения.

Answer (score 4):

Постфикс *"-ся"*  указывает не только на возвратность действия. Например, молиться — это же не молить самого себя, а кусаться — не кусать самого себя. Таких примеров много. Думаю, *"продается квартира"* вполне правомерный вариант. *"Продам (-ю) квартиру"* — тоже.

Answer (score 2):

> Может ли неодушевлённый предмет сам с собой производить действие?

Может.

Снег кружится
С. Березин Слова Л.Козлова

Такого снегопада, такого снегопада,
Давно не помнят здешние места.
А снег не знал и падал, а снег не знал и падал,
Земля была прекрасна прекрасна и чиста.

***Снег кружится***, летает, летает,
И поземкою клубя,
Заметает зима, заметает
Все что было до тебя

На выпавший на белый, на выпавший на белый
На этот чистый невесомый снег
***Ложится*** самый первый, ложится самый первый
И робкий, и несмелый, на твой похожий ***след***.

***Раскинутся просторы, раскинутся просторы***
До самой дальней утренней зари,
Но верю я, что скоро, но верю я, что скоро
По снегу ***доберутся*** к тебе мои ***следы***.

Специально для Вас - в каждом куплете.

> Как правильно следует писать: "продам (-ю) квартиру" или можно "продаётся квартира".

Все правильно. Возвратный суффикс -ся в русском многофункционален. Насчитывют до пяти (или даже семи - по другой систематике) таких функций, из которых собственно возвратная (производство действия на себя) даже не самая частая.
В рассматриваемом примере суффикс несет значение страдательности (выполнения действия над объектом).
Подробнее посмотрите [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8229#82]).

Comment: Ваш вопрос некорректен. Это понятия разных сфер. Нет такой функуци "просто возвратность".

А вообше "свершится" - это особая группа глаголов, уоторые без -ся не употребляются (или употребляются очень ограниченно). Почему тагие глаголы нельзя классифицировать подобно всем остальным - для меня тоже некоторая загадка, возмодно потому, что эти глаголы могут иметь сразу несколько функциональных признаков. Так, "сыершиться" похоже и на общевозвратный глагол (типа нагибаться), и на страдательное значение. Но первое все-таки вернее.