# "Снег кружится, летает, летает, и, позёмкою КЛУБЯ, заметает зима..." Или клубясь?

Tags: грамотная-речь, деепричастия

*Снег кружится, летает, летает,

И, позёмкою **клубя**,

Заметает зима, заметает

Всё, что было до тебя.*
Л. Козлова. [Снег кружится](https://unotices.com/page-text.php?id=35228)

Очень люблю эту песню, но мне всегда казалось, что должно быть ***позёмкою клубясь***.
Я бы хотела знать Ваше мнение — как правильно?

Answer (score 2):

> [КЛУБИТЬ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C), -бит; нсв. 1. что. Вздымать клубами, свивать в клубы. Ветер клубил золу на пожарище. 2. Устар. =Клубиться. Пыль клубит.

Думаю, тут работает второй пункт (устаревшее клубить = клубиться). Зима клубит (клубится) поземкой. Рифма: клубя — тебя. А современный глагол *клубить* — переходный, требует после себя существительного в винительном падеже, которого здесь нет.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь оба варианта  являются **не совсем точными** по грамматике или по смыслу.

**1) Поземкою клубя (чем?)**

Этот вариант больше подходит по смыслу: зима клубит поземку, то есть  вздымает, свивает в клубы уже выпавший снег. Но Т.п. здесь неточный, нужен В.п. Хотя в принципе можно  допустить и Т.п. в качестве падежа, придающего действию определенный вид.

**2) Поземкою клубясь (клубя) (как?)**

Этот вариант (***клубясь***) более правилен грамматически (***клубя*** — устаревшая форма): поземка ***клубится/клубит***, **но образ получается другой,** менее ясный: зима уже не снег свивает клубами, а  **сама клубится/клубит в виде позёмки-метели и при этом  заметает всё вокруг**.

**Возможные выводы**

1) По смыслу здесь должно быть выражение ***поземкою клубясь***, **но сделана уступка точной рифме.** Однако в такой форме (***поземкою клубя***) этот смысл уже не прочитывается, так что получается: клубя (чем? не как?) поземкою. **Что делать, это погрешности поэтической речи.**

2) **Здесь действительно "поземкою клубя"**

Это Т.п., **инструментальный** падеж.

Снег, морозы, поземка-метель — всё это проявление зимы, её инструменты, материальные признаки отвлеченного понятия. **Клубиться зима в прямом смысле не может**, но может  клубить (что?) снег  (как?) поземкою (**в в виде поземки**) и заметать всё вокруг.

Comment: Я либеральнее отношусь к творительному падежу дополнения при глаголе "клубить". Если отвлечься от прописанной составителями переходности, то с творительным падежом можно приписать этому глаголу скрытый оттенок другого: "помыкать, заставляя клубиться" (метель клубит снег/снегом) - вместо обычного "клубит = заставляет клубиться".

Comment: Варианты могут быть разные. 1) Ветер клубил золу на пожарище (из словаря), здесь только В.п., переходность очевидна. 2) Озеро носит название Кипящее, так как воды нагреваются вулканическими газами.  Возле берега в некоторых местах вода бурлит, КЛУБИТ ПАРАМИ.  Здесь Т.п. : вода клубит парами (пары - это уже инструмент, хотя и связанный с водой). Другие варианты НЕ ПОДХОДЯТ: вода клубит пары (но пары - это тоже вода, они именно водяные, не другие), вода клубится парами.(но вода сама-то не клубится).

Comment: Вот и у нашей зимы подобная ситуация. Снег, морозы, поземка-метель - всё это проявление зимы,  материальные признаки отвлеченного понятия. Поэтому здесь похожая ситуация: клубится зима в прямом смысле не может, а клубить поземкою - пожалуйста. Может быть, это как раз нормальная грамматика.

Answer (score 2):

> Очень люблю эту песню, но мне всегда казалось, что должно быть
>   позёмкою клубясь. Я бы хотела знать Ваше мнение — как правильно?

Не думаю, что **должно.** Возможно, наверное, и *"клубясь"* -  не не более того. Допускаю, что вы (и Jasmin, кстати) не совсем верно понимаете грамматику фразы, а потому и смысл.

*Клубит* - это такая же форма как *"пылит", "дымит", "моросит"*. Судя по всему, она действительно становится несколько архаичной, но когда грамматика не предполагает иного, она вполне употребима. Грамматика тут, конечно, не совсем прозрачная, но все же я полагаю, что это ССП, осложненное деепричастным оборотом во второй части. То есть, избавляясь от деепричастной конструкции, имеем ***"Зима клубит поземкою"***. Таким образом перед нами типичная *инструментативная функция творительного падежа*.  Зима выступает в роли объекта, *поземкою* - объект, которым или с помощью которого выполняется действие. Сравните: *Петя играет ножичком, Вася ловит рыбу удочкой, учитель пишет мелом*. Ничего похожего на сравнительный оборот типа *"взлетел орлом"* или *"сверкнул змеёй"* тут нет.

Теперь что можно было бы сказать о конструкции "зима клубится поземкою"? 
У возвратной частицы в русском не одна функция (здесь подробно [Возвратный суффикс "ся"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8229)), но вариант прямого действия "клубит собой позёмкою" тут исключен, объект "занят". То есть это или сравнительный оборот (*"подобно позёмке"*), или что-то совсем разговорное (*"женщина убирается пылесосом", "девочка играется куклой"*). Есть, правда, еще взаимно-возвратная функция (*"мальчики дерутся кулаками"*), но здесь она по смыслу, да и по грамматике, не проходит. Чего-то еще в конструкции *"возвратный глагол + творительный падеж"* представить себе трудно. Все означенные варианты тут вряд ли применимы по смыслу или стилистике.

(+) Написал - и задумался насчет взаимно-возвратной функции. Скажем, *"войско отбивалось мечами"* ведь тоже некоторый неологизм. Раньше бы сказали *"билось на мечах"*. Бог знает, может и *"клубиться (чем?) поземкою"* когда-нибудь станет вполне законным. Но пока я этого не ощущаю.

(++) У Alex_ander обнаружил утверждение, что метель/позёмка клубиться не может. Я отчасти согласен, клубить(ся) - это образовывать **клубы**  - бесформенную массу чего-то, обычно в воздухе. Метели не очень свойственно, снег при метели движется скорее потоком, чем клубами. Но пусть автор так видит, его право. Это-то уже никак не относится к теме возвратности.

Comment: _...метель/позёмка клубиться не может._ У Ожегова: ПОЗЁМКА, -и, жен. и ПОЗЁМОК, -мка, муж. Метель без снегопада, поднимающая снег с поверхности земли. Поднялась, **закрутилась** поземка. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/169182

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова *У Ожегова...* - Эээээ... Не понял. Посмотрите еще на значение слова "клубить(ся)". Оно никак не связано с "крутиться". У Кузнецова, правда, есть значение клубиться=бурлить (о волнах), но даже оно очень натянуто. Впрочем, я уже сказал, что автор имеет  право на собственное в**и**денье, отличное от физического.

Answer (score 1):

Обернувшись **поземкою**, которая является разновидностью метели, **зима** на тех же основаниях, что метель, **клубит** (что? снег - это слово часто опускается и в отношении метели; *клубиться* же метель не может: это явление, а не вещество) путём создания завихрений из снега.

Comment: ВОСПИТАТЕЛЬ: В феврале метель клубится По широкой мостовой. Нынче празднуем рожденье Нашей армии родной.

Comment: *клубиться же метель не может: это явление, а не вещество* — в учебнике физики не может, а в стихотворных метафорах может не только метель, но и мгла, и темнота, и многое другое.

Comment: А в стихах наших современных поэтов что только не клубится, например: Месяц март позёмкою клубится. Из словаря: Клубился дым над избами. Дыхание паром клубится у рта. Это тоже явление, почему же оно клубится?

Comment: @Jasmin Дым и пар это материальное (вещество или смесь, если угодно). (классика: физики против лириков :)

Comment: У них же дыхание клубится,  а это уж точно явление, даже процесс.

Comment: У них дыхание пребывает в обличии пара, поэтому и поклубиться может :)

Comment: Так-то оно так, но мы говорим о формальной грамматике,  а словарный пример наводит на мысль, что это уже не художественная, а языковая метафора.

Comment: *клубиться же метель не может* - А почему вы отказываете "явлению" в праве быть производителем действия? Дым может дымиться? Гроза бушевать? Снег идти - в конце-то концов? Другое дело, что такое действие может быть не очень-то свойственно метели. Метель - она метет, максимум "завивается", до *клубов* тут далеко, но это уже авторское виденье...

Comment: Дым дымиться (= испускать дым) **не** может - это дело трубы, котелка и т. п. Гроза бушевать может - как явление и мера его интенсивности. Снег (вещество) может много как себя вести. Метель - это явление, не сводимое к геометрическим формам самодвижения: снег может клубить**ся** (при метели), сама метель - нет, она только **клубит** (что-то или чем-то, явно выраженным или подразумеваемым).