# Особенное значение глагола «лапать»

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов, глаголы

При формулировании вопроса [«Клубя или клубясь?»](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/443054/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%91%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8E-%D0%9A%D0%9B%D0%A3%D0%91%D0%AF-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%98%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%8F%D1%81%D1%8C) встретилось такое предложение:

*Миловидная барышня в платке **лапала** по снегу огромными валенками, клубя ртом синий и белый пар.*
[А. С. Грин. Фанданго](https://www.livelib.ru/book/120549/read-fandango-aleksandr-grin/~3)

Как Вы думаете, какое значение в этом контексте имеет глагол ***лапать***?
Почему автор выбрал именно это слово?

Comment: Aer, извините, я что-то пропустила? У нас теперь предпочтительнее в формулировке вопроса использовать _ёлочки_?

Comment: Римма, нет, можно использовать любые кавычки, но, кажется, обычно в русских (не электронных) текстах применяются елочки: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8#%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8,_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5.

Answer (score 3):

***Лапать*** — индивидуально-авторский неологизм. Вероятно, он построен по аналогии: ступня —  ступать,  лапа — лапать.

**Миловидная барышня в платке лапала по снегу огромными валенками**... [А. С. Грин. Фанданго (1927)]

**Одним словом не назовешь, как барышня перемещалась.**  Не скажешь, как скользили маленькие ножки в огромных валенках, придавая им направленное движение, а валенки при этом шлепали по снегу "в собственном свободном полёте". (Барышня, платок, валенки — всё это портрет того времени, данный в деталях).

**Или можно сказать иначе, "поправить" автора?**

Comment: Ну что Вы — **"поправить" автора**! Как можно? Просто искала обоснования своим ощущениям, своему восприятию. Спасибо, Вы подтвердили некоторые мои мысли.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос, для начала приведу выдержку из [исследования](http://grinworld.org/salvatory/salvatory_03_06_1.htm), посвященного языку А. С. Грина:

> В соответствии с поставленными эстетическими задачами писатель в своей индивидуально-авторской речи подвергает слова общенационального языка творческой **трансформации как в семантическом**, так и в стилистическом планах. При этом первостепенное значение приобретает включение слова **в систему словосочетаний, контекста**.

Глагол «лапать» связан со словом «лапа», которое обозначает руку или ногу, поэтому вполне возможно, что в данном контектсе он значит «(по-особому) ступать по чему-то». Вообще, «лапать» значит «щупать, **хватать** руками», так почему бы и не принять, что *лапать по снегу **огромными** валенками* =  *размашисто **неаккуратными** движениями ступать по снегу, при этом как бы копаясь в нем*?

Я думаю, что на выбор именно этого слова повлияло наличие оттенка значения, связанного с неосторожностью, небрежностью, неаккуратностью. Указание на размер валенок в какой-то степени подтверждает мое предположение, ведь с чем-то огромным трудно действовать аккуратно.